# "da", "el", or nothing?

Tags: prepositions, correlatives

Suppose I want to say something like "all/each/some/many of something". Which preposition should be used to represent the "of" here? "Da", "el", or nothing? Secondly, what preceding preposition should be used?

- "ĉiu(j) da/el/_ tiu(j)"
- "ĉiom da/el/_ tiuj"
- "multa(j) da/el/_ tiuj"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**el**

Note that *da* can never be used with something specific, because it represents a quantity of some generic thing, like a liquid or a type of object, or people, etc. See this remark from [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#da):

> Konsekvence, la subst., kiu venas post **da** ne devas esti determinata de:
>   **1 la** (Kp *kvaronjaro estas parto de la jaro*<sup>Z</sup> k *kvaronjaro estas peco da tempo*);
>   **2 ĉiuj** k **tuta** (Kp *nur kelkaj el ĉiuj voĉdonantoj* k *kelke da voĉdonantoj*);
>   **3** montraj, posedaj k nombraj determinantoj (Kp *iom de tiu ĉi kuko* k *iom da kuko*; *rento de mil dolaroj* k *mil dolaroj da rento*; *la nombro de niaj partianoj*<sup>Z</sup> k *multe da partianoj*);

and also

> La subst., kiu venas post **da**, ne povas mem esprimi precizan kvanton (Kp *parto de jaro* k *deko da jaroj*; *duono de monato* k *kelke da monatoj*).

Definition **I.5** of *el* in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#el) says the following:

> Prep. montranta […] [l]a aron, kies erojn oni deprenas aŭ abstraktas; la devenon de parto apartigita disde la tuto: *unu el ili*<sup>Z</sup>; *du el la plej fortoj*; *la plej fortaj el ĉiuj; kelkaj el la ĉefoj<sup>Z</sup> […]

So if you want to consider a specific subset of another specific group, you use *el*. If you want to express a quantity of a *generic* group or concept, you use *da*.

---

Specifically *ĉiu(j)* and *multaj* can work fine before *el*.

> ĉiu(j) de tiuj

With or without *j* means basically the same thing, but the nuance is different: With *ĉiu* you focus more on the individual thing. Note that *ĉiu el tiu* is a bit odd, because *tiu* is one specific thing. You can say *ĉio el tio* though (because *tio* can refer to a multitude of things).

> ĉiom el tiuj

This is a little odd, because *ĉiom* expresse a quantity, whilst *tiuj* expresses specific things. It would then be better to say *ĉiom el tio*.

> multaj el tiuj

This just means *many of those* and is fine. It would be weird to say *multa el tiuj*, because *tiuj* refers to several specific things, but *multa* is singular: so this makes no sense; you cannot have many of a bunch of objects that is singular! However, *multa el tio* does make sense, because *tio* can be something uncountable (like water).

Comment: What about "I have a lot of [those] cats"? "Multaj el [tiuj] katoj? What about "multe"?

Comment: Let's rephrase it; say your looking at many cars parked somewhere, you could then say "mi posedas multajn el tiuj aŭtoj".

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is trying to translate just *of*. The question, as it stands now, is not really answerable without visiting all possibilities (a lot).

See these examples (just for *all of*):

```
cleaning the kitchen just zapped all of my energy
  purigi la kuirejon ĉerpis mian tutan energion
  purigi la kuirejon elĉerpis mian energion

to convict all of them (from the bible)
  por kondamni ĉiujn malpiulojn

the baby ate all of his cereal
  la bebo manĝis la tutan cerealaĵon
  la bebo finmanĝis/finis sian cerealaĵon
```

As you can see, the meaning can be conveyed by *tut-*, *ĉiu(j)* or of the verb, with *el-* or *fin-*. But those are just some examples.

For *some of* and *many of* you will also have *kelk-*, *plur-*, *-iom-*, ... as possibilities.